# Segfault (possibly due to casting)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I don't normally go to stackoverflow for sigsegv errors, but I have done all I can with my debugger at the moment.

The segmentation fault error is thrown following the completion of the function. Any ideas what I'm overlooking? I suspect that it is due to the casting of the sockaddr to the sockaddr_in, but I am unable to find any mistakes there. (Removing that line gets rid of the seg fault -- but I know that may not be the root cause here).

```
// basic setup
int sockfd;
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
sockaddr* sa;
socklen_t* sl;
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
int rv;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

// return string
string foundIP;

// setup the struct for a connection with selected IP
if ((rv = getaddrinfo("4.2.2.1", NULL, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return "1";
}

// loop through all the results and make a socket
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("talker: socket");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

if (p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "talker: failed to bind socket\n");
    return "2";
}

// connect the UDP socket to something
connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen); // we need to connect to get the systems local IP

// get information on the local IP from the socket we created
getsockname(sockfd, sa, sl);

// convert the sockaddr to a sockaddr_in via casting
struct sockaddr_in *sa_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)sa;

// get the IP from the sockaddr_in and print it
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa_ipv4->sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
printf("%s\n", str);

// return the IP
return foundIP;
```

}

Comment: Did you use -Wall flag for gcc? sometimes some warning are hidden, and they help to find out the problem.

Comment: Notice that you can also use p->ai_addr instead of sa:
struct sockaddr_in *sa_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)sa; would become  struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;

Comment: How foolish of me -- I never allocated memory to that pointer. My apologizes -- the end of the day is getting to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like you ever initialize the pointer `sa` to point at a valid `sockaddr` (or `sockaddr_in`) object.

If you replace

```
sockaddr* sa;
```

with

```
sockaddr addr;
```

and replace all uses of `sa` with `&addr` you should be in better shape.

The same is also true of `sl`. At least according to the documentation for my getsockname the `socklen_t*` parameter needs to point at a valid `socklen_t` object initialized to the size in bytes of the address buffer.

E.g.

```
socklen_t slen = sizeof addr;
```

and use `&slen` instead of `sl`.

Comment: If you know the protocol, such as IPv4, `sockaddr_in` or similar would be a better choice. If you don't know the protocol, `sockaddr_storage` would be a better choice.

Comment: @Thanatos: Possibly, yes. It's work checking your platform. On mine, `sockaddr` is big enough for a `sockaddr_in` and which ever one you choose you have to do some casting of pointers where you need the other one. The important think is to specify the buffer length correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you don't ever set up the sa pointer to actually point at anything. Commenting out the line "struct sockaddr_in *sa_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)sa;" should cause a compile error, so I guess I can see how not being able to compile your program would also cause it to not segfault - hard for a non-existent binary to crash :)

Comment: Sorry -- meant to say if I comment out that line and the line(s) below it.

Answer (score 1):

You did not allocate `sa` before passing it to `getsockname`, so you effectively passed in some garbage pointer value there. It needs to be:

```
struct sockaddr_in sa;
socklen_t sl;
...
getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, &sl);
...
```

Comment: Ummm, you're casting a `struct sockaddr **` to a `struct sockaddr*`.  Did you mean that?

Comment: @Charles: where am I doing that? The variable is not of the pointer type; applying `&` adds one level of indirection.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at your new getsockname call and the original declarations. I hadn't spot that you'd fixed the types. I'll delete my comments in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

just to add, valgrind is pretty useful in detecting uninitialized pointers or for that matter any pointer related errors.

Comment: Thanks -- I was unaware of this tool set. memcheck looks particularly useful.